# Using reinforcement learning to optimize a state-based potential function

Tags: reinforcement-learning, potential-reward-shaping, episodes

I am using reinforcement learning for a project, and the objective function I want to optimize is a potential-based function. In other words, it is preferable for the agent to move to positions with higher potential.

My questions are: 1. Can I directly use the potential function as the reward function? 2. Since I don't know the optimal location of the potential in advance, the length of the sequence cannot be predetermined. How should I choose the length of an episode in such a situation?

I'll appreciate any suggestion and comment.

Comment: Are you required to use RL for this? How is the value/potential value being sampled?

Comment: @NeilSlater At the initial state, the agent is randomly assigned to a position. Our goal is for the agent to output an action to move itself, thereby increasing the potential of its current position. It is similar to mountain climbing. I'm uncertain if my description is clear.

Comment: OK, I understand that. This is an unusual way to find a solution to multivariable nonlinear optimisation. You can make it work, but RL is an odd choice here, and I wondered why? One reason might be because you really want to see what happens with an RL agent in this situation. However, there are better choices, especially if calculating values of your potential is easy.